# Бойлерплейт vue.js + бэкэнд на node.js

Tags: frontend, vue.js, spa

Как организовать разработку одностраничного приложения в рамках одного проекта?

Создал я заготовку с помощью vue-cli, она крутится на девелоперском сервере на своём порту.
Приступил я к созданию бэкэнд-апи на ноде - оно работает на другом порту. При взаимодействии с фронтендом начались проблемы - порты разные, прыжки от одного окна редактора к другому и тд.

Я понимаю, что проблема на ровном месте, но ума не приложу, как это всё сделать, чтобы работало всё на одном порту, само авторелоадилось ну, и, в конечном счёте, чтобы это всё в докер упаковать можно было и запустить на сервере.
Как у нормальных людей это устроено? Где можно посмотреть?

Comment: Ваш вопрос требует раскрыть не мало тем. Попробуйте тут найти свой ответ. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrpvmiGAeKSkmM-fpyuwYjw

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно)